# Magento 1.9.3.1 30 second TTFB Caused by BLOCK ACTION: top.links -> addLink

Tags: magento-1.9, profiler

I've a site that's been up for the previous year without issue, however recently it has an extremely long **TTFB of over 30 seconds** when loading anything.

I've installed **AOE profiler** which tells me its being caused by **BLOCK ACTION:**

> top.links -> addLink

Would anyone know how I might go about fixing this?

Many thanks.

[image: AOE Profiler Result]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has a similar issue - I solved this by disabling the top links block. Not an ideal solution, but the site is performing well again. It may be something to do with the template being used - Ultimo.